# Rest assured- comparing api response with java object

Tags: java, api, rest, automated-tests, rest-assured

can you tell me if there is any way to compare API response with java object using only Rest Assured?
I would like to have a test looks like below:

```
    var response = api.getRequest();
    response.statusCode(200);
    response.body(JsonValidator.matches........)
    response.body(<test of comparing objects>)
```

I know I can use hamcrest
`assertThat("comment", response.extract.as( XZY.class), equalTo(XXX.class))`.
But maybe there is solution for my question :)
Thanks for any tips ! :)

Comment: No, you have to convert response to java object them use Hamcrest to compare.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17, Hamcrest won't do - its current reflection comparison is quite limited. Unitils' assertReflectionEquals() is much more comprehensive.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev I don't know about internal things in Hamcrest. I just use Hamcrest to compare 2 objects with overrided `Equals()` and `hashCode()`. Is this correct?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant to leverage Hamcrests + AssertJ and leverage `isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively()`. As for `equals()` & `hashCode()` - you don't want to rely on them in tests - see my comment to Alex Karamfilov answer.

Answer (score 0):

RestAssured doesn't have (and shouldn't have) this capability. A typical approach to this is:

```
SomeClass expected = ...;
SomeClass actual = given().get(...).as(SomeClass.class);
assertReflectionEquals(expected, actual);
```

`assertReflectionEquals()` comes from Unitils.